# deleting primary key in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How do I go about deleting primary key like a `product_id` in Entity Framework code-first, if later on a primary key is not needed? Is it by simply removing the flag `[id]` or is there some other way also?

Comment: Every table should have a primary key, it should never be "not needed."

Comment: A primary key is ***always needed*** - don't even *think* about removing it!

Answer (score 0):

EF does not support tables without primary Keys.
BTW the attribute is [Key]